# Is there any performance hit to setting a list as itself?

Tags: c#, performance, list

I have a list that may be null if not yet instantiated, and I want when calling GetList() to be able to return existing or create the list and then return. This looks cleaner:

```
private List<object> m_objects;
public List<object> GetList()
{
    m_objects = m_objects ?? new List<object>();
    return m_objects;
}
```

But is there a performance hit for setting the list as itself, or does C# realize that that's not necessary?

The alternative would be:

```
private List<object> m_objects;
public List<object> GetList()
{
    if(m_objects != null) 
    {
        return m_objects;
    }
    m_objects = new List<object>();
    return m_objects;
}
```

Obviously not the end of the world but I'm still curious.

Comment: Or simply: `private readonly List<object> m_objects = new List<object>(); public List<object> GetList(){return m_objects;}`

Comment: As with any performance question you can of course simply test it.  Though I seriously doubt there would be much of a difference.

Comment: For starters, we won't always want the object new'd up if we aren't going to use it every time.  I would go as far as calling this lazy initialization

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Dd642331(v=VS.110).aspx):

```
private Lazy<List<object>> m_objects = new Lazy<List<object>>();
public List<object> GetList()
{
    return m_objects.Value;
}
```

Addressing the performance issue. Worrying about performance here is premature optimisation. You should code it first to just work and then if you see any performance related problems, profile it and optimise.

Comment: What does lazy does? Any reference included at least would be better as an answer IMHO.

Comment: @BeytanKurt You can look at the documentation for the type if you want to learn more.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx is the microsoft documentation page.  But basically, it will initialise the object when it is first required it will either create the type based of the default constructor of T or use an initialising method if presented with one in the constructor of Lazy<T>().  Note, if you use WPF or Winforms objects with Lazy, ensure you are on the UI thread when you first obtain the .Value or you will cause threading issues in a multi-threaded environment.  You can also initalise Lazy<> so it is not multi-thread aware for performance.

Comment: While `Lazy<T>` is certainly a good option in general, I don't think it improves performance here.

Comment: Worrying about performance here is quite premature optimisation.

Comment: While I principally agree about premature optimization I also understand the OP's motivation: It's valuable to avoid getting used to badly performing programming styles if the alternatives do not compromise readability etc.

Comment: I would believe, that `Lazy` is quite optimized :)

Comment: @MichałKędrzyński It will unquestionably be much slower than every single other option shown.  It's simply doing a lot more, and that added functionality has its price in performance.  It's reasonably optimized *for what it does* but it can't really compete with just doing a whole bunch less.

Comment: @Servy Now that is a bold statement. Can you show any data? (My assumption is that it must perform one additional indirection with every `.value` (namely `.value`)  which seems as likely to be optimized away as the unnecessary assignment in the OP, and is probably about as fast if indeed performed.

Comment: @PeterSchneider It'll need to handle synchronization as it is required to handle calls from multiple threads at the same time.  That is unquestionably going to be more expensive than assigning a reference to itself, whether that assignment is optimized away or not.

Comment: @Servy If I understand the documentation correctly, synchronization is optional. Cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd989799%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Found some code for `Lazy`: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Lazy@cs/1305376/Lazy@cs It seems that there is additional boxing and casting here. This would of course be slower.

Comment: @PeterSchneider And it's not disabled here.  I wouldn't expect it to be *dramatically* more expensive; it's not likely to be significant at all, but the OP's code is, in the worst case, performing a superfluous assignment of one registry value from another, so it's about as fast of an operation as you can possibly have.  I'm sure all of the options are *good enough*, but I have no doubt that this would be slower (by some marginal amount) than every other option.

Comment: To be honest I just realised that all the talk about thead safety is mute given that List<T> isn't thread safe anyway so you're only applying thread safety to the list reference, not the values.

Comment: Well of course, but consider the situation in which 2 threads are getting value at the same time. `Lazy` ensures, that it will be the same value, not 2 different lists. This is the case `Lazy` is for. The inner object's thread safety is another issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly valid:

```
private List<string> items;
public List<string> Items { get { return items ?? (items = new List<string>()); } }
```

note the `?? (items =` difference. There is no performance hit as it is boolean short circuited at `??` if it has a non null value.

---

As pointed out, in case you want to use your code, then YES, it does pose performance hit as new element is created each time.

Comment: Using **object** is not something you usually want to do - for example **dynamic** or **Lazy<>** is better.

Comment: This isn't actually answering the question being asked.

Comment: Don't think the question asks for an alternative, it asks if that specific style gives an overhead

Comment: I think it's a valid answer. The OP may not have thought of embedding the test for null and the conditional assignment  *in the return statement* proper (as opposed to having it in a separate statement which is therefore always executed).

Comment: After the "yes, it does" added, both answers the question and gives an easy & clever alternative.

Comment: After your edit: No "object is created every time" in the OP's code, or am I missing something? A *reference* is assigned to itself, unless the assignment is optimized away (which probably was what the OP was asking).

Answer (score 1):

As the question specifically asks for performance, this gives you the best possible performance when calling `GetList()` and it's thread safe:

```
private readonly List<object> m_objects = new List<object>();
public List<object> GetList()
{
    return m_objects;
}
```

Another option for making it thread safe would be using `Lazy<T>`. This defers the `new List<object>()` at the expense of always doing `new Lazy<List<object>>()` with additional overhead in the `GetList()` method.

Comment: This is probably the best usage as long as there aren't a lot of `m_objects` being created by creating lots of its parent class.  If GetList() is only called against a fraction of the parent class, this would have created lots of empty lists, and run a lot of list constructors unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

There will probably be a minimal performance hit because you are basically assigning the reference held in `m_objects` to the `m_objects` field. That is effectively just copying a 64 or 32-bit pointer. You wouldn't be copying around all the data, just the reference to the instance of the object (or null).

For your code, I think using the ?? quotations is very neat and adequate as long as you aren't worried about multiple threading.  If you are, then the Lazy<> suggest that @Michał Kędrzyński suggested is the better way to go since you wouldn't need to program all that in.

The only exception being if that you needed to make sure you were on the Dispatcher thread in WPF or the UI thread in Winforms due to UI limitations.

**Edit**

Just to correct my own answer, using Lazy is moot if your generic type isn't thread-safety aware anyway (for example, List isn't thread safe)

Comment: Good point I have been leaving comments so automatically did the same against mine instead of editing like I normally do ! Oops but thanks for pointing it out